# Can't get Bootstrap jQuery or bootstrap CSS to work

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ok, so I've been coding HTML and CSS for a bit and I'm now looking into designing full webpages. My dad is a developer and he suggested Bootstrap since he has seen a lot of companies moving towards responsive websdesign. So here I am. I've been through multiple tutorials i deff get the gist of it and it seems awesome. But heres my problem:

I can't get it to work, so I can test it!!!

I have the code written out here and I just want to create a 4 column layout but everytime I open it in Chrome it dosen't seem to reference the Bootstrap CSS or jQuery files. Please,  help 
:(

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<!--column 1-->
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>header 1</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ut nulla      venenatis, gravida sapien sed, condimentum dolor. Phasellus gravida orci non rhoncus vehicula.</p>
            <p><a href="#">Read more >></a></p>
        </div>
<!--column 2-->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>header 2</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ut nulla      venenatis, gravida sapien sed, condimentum dolor. Phasellus gravida orci non rhoncus vehicula.</p>
            <p><a href="#">Read more >></a></p>
        </div>
<!--column 3-->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>header 3</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ut nulla      venenatis, gravida sapien sed, condimentum dolor. Phasellus gravida orci non rhoncus vehicula. </p>
            <p><a href="#">Read more >></a></p>
        </div>
<!--column 4-->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>header 4</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ut nulla      venenatis, gravida sapien sed, condimentum dolor. Phasellus gravida orci non rhoncus vehicula.</p>
             <p><a href="#">Read more >></a></p>
         </div>
    </div>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the page load at all?  What does this mean: "doesn't seem to reference the Bootstrap Css or jQuery files"

Comment: only the headers and paragraphs load. the bootstrap isnt kicking in

Comment: Are you running this from a webserver or are you loading this file locally in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Bootstrap 4 as it is the latest version. In this case, you need to import couple of script links viz. bootstrap.min.css, jquery.js, popper js, bootstrap.min.js.

**Without these links your bootstrap won't work**

I have added a **container** class so that it looks responsive.

**Please note:** You have used **.col-md-3**. So in the result code snippet below you will find all these columns are stacked this is because the screen size is not enough. 
I have used **.col-sm-3** so that it fits properly in the screen space and it is responsive.

So here you go.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <h4>header 1</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ut nulla venenatis, gravida sapien sed, condimentum dolor. Phasellus gravida orci non rhoncus vehicula.</p>
      <p><a href="#">Read more >></a></p>
    </div>
    <!--column 2-->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <h4>header 2</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ut nulla venenatis, gravida sapien sed, condimentum dolor. Phasellus gravida orci non rhoncus vehicula.</p>
      <p><a href="#">Read more >></a></p>
    </div>
    <!--column 3-->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <h4>header 3</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ut nulla venenatis, gravida sapien sed, condimentum dolor. Phasellus gravida orci non rhoncus vehicula. </p>
      <p><a href="#">Read more >></a></p>
    </div>
    <!--column 4-->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <h4>header 4</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ut nulla venenatis, gravida sapien sed, condimentum dolor. Phasellus gravida orci non rhoncus vehicula.</p>
      <p><a href="#">Read more >></a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This should do the trick except, you should put boostrap's js files right before the end of body tag as instructed in bootstrap website.

Comment: @OzanAyten good catch. Thanks for pointing out. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `http://{link}` instead of just `//`. If you're running it on a server the `//` is ok. If you're just opening the file in Chrome then it assumes `file://{link}` which is nothing.

Comment: You should always test on a server. There are a couple that you can download and run on your desktop/laptop.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting http:// in the CDN links:

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```